# Laravel sum value from different tables and looping it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello guys i want to ask how to sum total from different tables and looping it, how can i do that ?

Here is my tables :

**Outcomes :**

```
- id
- total
```

**Incomes :**

```
- id
- total
```

And this is what i've tried :

My Controller :

```
$outcomes = Outcome::where('user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);
$incomes = Income::where('user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)->paginate(10);

return view('myview', compact('outcomes','incomes'));
```

and the result is:

I don't want the result like this :

[image]

I want the result like this (hard coded) :

[image]

Comment: Just replace `->paginate(10);` by `->sum('total');`

Comment: I've to looping all the records from both tabel, and sum it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count of records (how many records) you do:

```
$query = DB::table('Outcome')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as outcome_count'))
    ->get();
```

You can see more here [Laravel raw db expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Then to get the outcome_count you have to do:

```
$query[0]->outcome_count;
```

To sum a value from each row you have to do:

```
$query2 = DB::table('Outcome')
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(Outcome.{theValueYouWantToSum}) AS total'))
    ->get();
```

and get the value

```
$query2[0]->total;
```

You can read about mysql functions here: [mysql functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

Comment: ok i got all the value both from my table and my another table, but now how can i sum it???

Comment: What do you mean? You add the values from each query.

Comment: I want to sum each row from outcomes and incomes tables

Comment: @daffaquraisy I have updated my answer. Have a look!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate !